# My discord bot is creating a role but the name of the role is coming as "new role"

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, roles

In my console it is printing Created new role with the name of new role,
here is my code

```
const roleManager=guild.roles;
    roleManager.create({
      data: {
        name: 'My Role',
        color: 'GREEN',
        mentionable: true,
        reason: 'Creating a new role'
      },
    })
      .then(role => console.log(`Created new role with name ${role.name}`))
      .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Current docs show that there is no `data` property in the role create options: https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create

Comment: So i just remove data? @Elitezen

Comment: Yes, along with the extra `{}`. You can follow the example code in the documentation

Comment: ok thanks once again but last question , how do I ping a role using the roleId @Elitezen ??

Comment: and also pls check my account i have another question